# omnidirectional camera in gazebo

Tags: gazebo, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I want simulate my robot in the gazebo, but I can't find omnidirectional camera in the gazebo,my carmera is like  this. Do you have idea about this?

[image description http://robotics.sjtu.edu.cn/UpFiles/EditorFile/image/201105/20110506163403204.jpg](http://robotics.sjtu.edu.cn/UpFiles/EditorFile/image/201105/20110506163403204.jpg)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38155/omnidirectional-camera-in-gazebo/) by [igoliao](https://answers.ros.org/users/2527/igoliao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2012-07-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have not tried it but...

You may want to have a look at this:
https://kforge.ros.org/pipermail/gazebo-list/2007-November/002173.html

---

Originally posted by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) with karma: 387 on 2012-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0